# Load settings without persistence in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, encryption, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux, persistence

I created a 32 GB bootable USB drive with [E2B](http://www.easy2boot.com/), because I would like to have a pendrive that I have many distros and Windows installers on it.

I had pendrives with Kali linux on it, and it was really fast, but it was kind of tedious changing the **keyboard settings** (US to Hungarian) and entering the **Wi-Fi password** after every reboot that I had to do because I wanted to do something on Windows.

I thought persistence is the solution for that, so it would remember what I modified in the OS.
So I followed [this guide](http://rmprepusb.blogspot.com/2014/05/add-kali-linux-v107-luks-encrypted.html) to make the persistence enabled, and I also made it encrypted.
After it booted it was a sudden realization, that it is very slow.
I searched for solution, but it appeared that [there is no proper way to solve](http://www.linux.org/threads/ubuntu-liveusb-becomes-slow-after-adding-persistant-memory.7967/) for that.

As the post above explains, in live disc mode, you basically just read from the pendrive.
In the persistence mode, you are reading and writing to the drive, and the writing part will slow every process down, including while its trying to read, because it has to wait for a writing process to finish.
If you even encrypt it, it will be even worse, because as in the thread one post claims, the on-the-fly encryption is slowing it down even more.
Not even talking about the possibility of shortening the life expectancy of the flash.

My requirement for a possible solution would be that from the pendrive it would load at least:

- Keyboard/Language settings
- Wi-Fi password for known networks

Is this something that can be done without recompiling the OS from source or not?

BONUS: I tried to disable the beeping when the Kali menu first appears after booting, I opened the Kali iso, and removed the ASCII `BEL` character from the menu.cfg, but when I try to save it, it says read only. Also, is this something that can be somehow saved in the iso, without recompiling from source?

Comment: When presented with this problem on Ubuntu, I've not used persistence, but I added a directory and post-installation script which made the necessary modifications (eg updating `/etc/NetworkManager/` from files in the directory, saved from a configured system). Adding extra files is easy on a pen-drive, but to update an ISO, you will need to use a CD/DVD burning program to make a new copy from all the files on the original, plus the extra files you want to include, then make it bootable before saving.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a bunch of iso files on your usb drive, then it should be easy to open the iso and add or edit a few files, I'm pretty sure Archive Manager (for Gnome) can do it just like a .tar.gz or other archive, ***if you know what files to add/edit***.

But if you've "written" the iso to it's own partition on your usb drive, then it's probably in a read-only cd format (iso9660?), so you'd have to find & edit the original iso file & then write it.
Or, my favourite, add a "personal" partition to your usb drive and save a few config files (network settings, config files in home, etc), then after booting the live Kali mount your "personal"  partition & copy over the config files. Write a bash script to copy them & kill/restart any services that need to read the new config too. A logout/login may be required? But NOT a reboot, just like any live linux all system files (in overlay/tmpfs) will be lost at shutdown/reboot.

### Increase system read speed A LOT (but boot slower)

If you've got about an extra gig of RAM, and if Kali supports it (most Debian-based distros do) use the `toram` boot option to copy all the system files to RAM. Then any reads/write to the "system files" (basically everything in `/` that's not on a physical drive) will be at RAM/tmpfs speeds, probably 2GB to 10GB a second.